# Icons not Appearing and Animation not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, icons, font-awesome

I'm trying to use icons from fontawesome to create a menu that will pop up on the mobile version of my site. However, the icons do not appear and are not clickable, thus the animation that makes the menu pop up does not work. In addition, some of the items do not have their own row, as seen in the gallery and cv section, and the text on my homepage is not centered. Could someone please explain how to fix these issues? Thank you![enter image description here][1]

```css
*{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}
.header{
        min-height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,0.7),rgba(4,9,30,0.7)),url(images/banner.png);
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
}
nav{
    display: flex;
    padding: 2% 6%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
nav a{      
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 18px;
}
nav a:hover{
    color:#f44336;
    transition: .4s;
}
.nav-links{
        flex:1;
        text-align: right;
}
.nav-links ul li{
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        position: relative;
}
.nav-links ul li a{
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 13px;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
    color:#f44336;
    transition: .4s;
}
.text-box{
        width: 90%;
        color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        text-align: center;
}
.text-box h1{
    font-size: 54px;
}
.text-box p{
    margin: 10px 0 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}

nav .fa{
        display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 700px){
        .text-box h1{
                font-size: 20px;
        }
        .navi-links ul li{
            display: block;
        }
        .nav-links{
            position: absolute;
            background: #f44336;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 200px;
            top: 0;
            right: -200px;
            text-align: left;
            z-index: 2;
            transition: 1s;
        }
        nav .fa{
            display: block;
            color: #fff;
            margin: 10px;
            font-size: 22px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .nav-links ul{
            padding: 30px;
        }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="with=device-width, initial-scale=">
        <title>Personal Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css">
<style>
.text-box{
background-color: transparent;
color: #FFF;
margin: 20px;
padding: 20px;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="header">
            <nav>
                <a href="index.html">AMANDA YEE</a>
                <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
                  <i class="fa fa-times-circle" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">GALLERY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">CV</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
            </nav>
            
<div class="text-box">
    <h1>NICE TO MEET YOU</h1>
    <p>Hi! My name is Amanda Yee and I'm a User Experience Designer studying at Pratt.
    </p>
</div>

</section>

<!--Javascript for Toggle Menu-->
    <script>
        var navLinks = document.getElementbyId("navLinks");
        
        function showMenu(){
            navLinks.style.right = "0";
        }
        function hideMenu(){
            navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
        }
    </script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use font awesome 5 icons, go to their official website and create a kit using your email address. They will provide you a script tag add that script tag in your HTML file's head and now you are good to use fa icons. One thing to note is that now `fa fa-bars` will be `fas fa-bars`.

The thing why `Gallery` and `CV` are showing in a row is you have set wrong class name in your media query:

```
.navi-links ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

In addition to this, I will propose few changes to your file-

In the 4th line replace the viewport meta tag with the below code:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

In your script `document.getElementbyId` is not properly written replace that line with the below code:

```
var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");
```

I hope it worked as you expected.